# MongoDB Regex not return the proper result

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I have a query regarding the search on mongodb. On my table, there is around 5000 entries of Data. So I have to search the data on behalf of multiple columns with few priority.
Like first priority is symbol, name, co_name, bse_symbol, prev_symbol, isin, sc_code.
So on my query I searched the key i.e "DEN" and my code will return the data which are as follow in which the exact search i.e DEN is coming on 6th position instead of 1st because this is the exact match. My Code is returning the data which are as follows:

```
[
    {
        "co_name": "Aarvee Denims",
        "symbol": "AARVEEDEN",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "",
        "name": "Aarvee Denims & Exports Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "Confidence Finan",
        "symbol": "CONFINT",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "CONFINT",
        "name": "Confidence Finance & Trading Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "Confidence Fut.",
        "symbol": "CFEL",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "CFEL",
        "name": "Confidence Futuristic Energetech Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "Confidence Petro",
        "symbol": "CONFIPET",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "CONFIPET",
        "name": "Confidence Petroleum India Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "DE Nora India",
        "symbol": "DENORA",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "",
        "name": "DE Nora India Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "Den Networks",
        "symbol": "DEN",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "",
        "name": "Den Networks Ltd"
    },
    {
        "co_name": "Denis Chem Lab",
        "symbol": "DENISCHEM",
        "prev_symbol": "",
        "bse_symbol": "DENISCHEM",
        "name": "Denis Chem Lab Ltd"
    }..... etc etc
]
```

Here I am sharing my Node.js code.

```
const rejectSpecialCharacter = req.body.searchterm.replace(
                /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,
                '',
            );
            // convert user input into upper case to get the result
            const searchQueryUpperCase = rejectSpecialCharacter.toUpperCase();
            if (rejectSpecialCharacter === '') {
                return res.send({Message: 'Oops! no or wrong input provided'});
            }

            // Search Code, Symbol, ISIN, Company Name
            const regex = rejectSpecialCharacter
                .split(' ')
                .map(x => `(?=.*${x})`)
                .join('');
            //console.log(regex)
            const searchQuery = new RegExp(regex, 'i');
            let searchData = await MyTable.find(
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            $or: [
                                // { $text: { $search: rejectSpecialCharacter } },
                                { symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { co_name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { prev_symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { bse_symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archivesymbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archiveco_name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archivename: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { isin: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { sc_code: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                            ],
                        },
                        { internal_status: 'Active' },
                        // { internal_status: { $ne: 'Delisted' } },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    _id: 0,
                    symbol: 1,
                    name: 1,
                    co_name: 1,
                    bse_symbol: 1,
                    prev_symbol: 1,

                },
            )
                .limit()
                .exec();
            return res.send(searchData)
```

Is there anyone who suggest me that where I am doing mistakes by which My result not comes on first position.
**PS: I need to get the exact match entry on top and then after other matching enteries**

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue then. You are trying to store it into a variable. It should be more like the following:

```
const pathToModel = '/model.js';
router.post('/your-endpoint', (req, res) =>{
     const rejectSpecialCharacter = req.body.searchterm.replace(
                /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,
                '',
            );
     // convert user input into upper case to get the result
     const searchQueryUpperCase = rejectSpecialCharacter.toUpperCase();
      if (rejectSpecialCharacter === '' || !searchQueryUpperCase) {
          return res.send({Message: 'Oops! no or wrong input provided'});
      }else{
        const regex = rejectSpecialCharacter
              .split(' ')
              .map(x => `(?=.*${x})`)
              .join('');
            //console.log(regex);
        // Search Code, Symbol, ISIN, Company Name
         const searchQuery = new RegExp(regex, 'i');
         // the data passed should use diffrent names due to 'shadow' referencing but, javascript is good enough to figure it out but, it's just poor practice. I applied it hear for readability.
         pathToModel.operation({searchQuery: searchQuery, rejectSpecialCharacter: rejectSpecialCharacter}, function(error, success){
               if(error){
                  return res.status(404).json(error);
               }else if(success && !res.headerSent){
                  return res.status(200).json(success);
              }
         });
      }
});

// you model file
const operation = async (data, callback) =>{
   await MyTable.find(
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            $or: [
                                // { $text: { $search: rejectSpecialCharacter } },
                                { symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { co_name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { prev_symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { bse_symbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archivesymbol: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archiveco_name: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { archivename: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { isin: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                                { sc_code: { $regex: searchQuery } },
                            ],
                        },
                        { internal_status: 'Active' },
                        // { internal_status: { $ne: 'Delisted' } },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    _id: 0,
                    symbol: 1,
                    name: 1,
                    co_name: 1,
                    bse_symbol: 1,
                    prev_symbol: 1,

                },
            )
                .limit()
                .exec(function(error, success){
              if(error) callback(error, null);
              callback(null, success);
    });
}
```

Dependent on the version of mongoose there is support for using promises instead of callbacks, so keep in mind both the query and the return can be optimized.

Comment: This is not helpful. You have wrote the code into other way which not matters. And forget about the Node or mongoose. This query directly run on mongodb return the same result which I am mentioning on Question. There is nothing related to node code or mongoose.

Comment: The intention of rewriting the code would be to highlight the use of callback and not storing the query & result in the same variable, as shown in your code. In almost every code example or implementation of mongoose you find online the entire query is not store in a variable because it's poor practice. try the code rewritten make necessary changes and determine if it's helpful rather than completely ruling the solution out. Literally would take a few minutes.